# Flask application with Jinja - if statements won't work on Heroku

Tags: python, html, heroku, jinja2

I'm doing a web application with Flask. I have also Jinja2 library installed. Locally Jinja's `{% if something something %}` statements work, but not on Heroku where I'm supposed to run my program.

Here are all the dependencies for my application:

```
astroid==2.2.5
Click==7.0
Flask==1.0.2
Flask-Login==0.4.1
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.3.2
Flask-WTF==0.14.2
gunicorn==19.9.0
isort==4.3.15
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.10.1
lazy-object-proxy==1.3.1
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
mccabe==0.6.1
psycopg2==2.7.7
pylint==2.3.1
rope==0.14.0
six==1.12.0
SQLAlchemy==1.3.1
typed-ast==1.3.1
Werkzeug==0.14.1
wrapt==1.11.1
WTForms==2.2.1
```

```
{% if current_user.role == "superadmin" or current_user.role == "admin" %}
  <li class="nav-item active">
    <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url_for('worker_form') }}">Add new worker</a>
  </li>
...
{% endif %}
```

This part is what is not working on Heroku. I'm using Bootstrap's navbar in my application. Whenever the current user is *admin* or *superadmin*, there should be 4 more tabs in the navbar.

There's no error messages, it just doesn't show the admin tabs on Heroku.

Comment: Welcome to SO! What do you get if you stick `{{ current_user.role }}` before the if statement? Plus where is `current_user.role` coming from?

Comment: maybe the user is not login. try <p>{{ current_user.role }}</p> before if statement.